# Going back to the previous page

Tags: api, pagination, google-places-api

When using Google Places API you execute `pagination.nextPage()` to get the next set of data.

How can you go back to the previous page?

`pagination.prevPage()`, `pagination.previousPage()`, `pagination.backPage()` do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to the previous page is not possible via the current client. I suggest that you temporarily store each page as you move through them, if you need to support reverse pagination.